# How to get derivatives from Taylor series

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I recently started learning about Taylor series and getting the derivative is confusing from the sum provided. So for example if I had the Taylor series
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{k!}{(2k)!}(x-4)^k$$
how would I get derivatives from this for example $f ''(4)$?

Comment: Your series does not have the letter x in it. You must have left something out, like an x to a power in there.

Comment: @coffeemath yeah sorry just added it

Comment: Just take two derivatives term by term. At that point only the first term will not be zero when you plug in 4. [keep in mind that for power series terms the $0$ power is considered 1.]

Comment: From the general Taylor series, you can see that $\frac{f^{(k)}(4)}{k!}= (-1)^{k+1}\frac{k!}{(2k)!}$.

Comment: What exactly is confusing you? Please be specific.

Answer (score 10):

For Taylor series $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}(x-a)^n$, here $c_{n}$ is Taylor coefficient which is of the form $$c_{n}=\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$$
So $f^{(n)}(a)=n!\cdot c_n$.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I did not see that an answer has already been posted a few minutes before mine (I was typing out this answer when it was posted)  that uses a similiar method as mine, but as beginner myself, I feel the need to explain steps more thoroughly and the thinking behind employing this method, so I am posting the following answer :

Because the taylor series is centered about 4 (the summation is of powers of (x-4)) and we are asked about f"(4) we can think about differentiating both sides. This is because we know that when we differentiate a function (to find the value at x =4 4) such as $(x-4) + (x-4)^2 + (x-4)^3$ the differential of the higher powers at x = 4 have resultant value = $0$ because of the fact that when we differentiate $(x-4)^n (n > 1)$ we get a factor of (x-4) which at $x = 4\;is\; 0$

So taking our function $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{k!}{(2k)!}(x-4)^k$ and splitting it, we get :

$f(x) = -1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{k!}{(2k)!}(x-4)^k$

Differentiating both sides with respect to x, we get :

$f'(x) = \frac{d(-1)}{dx} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{k!}{(2k)!}\frac{d((x-4)^k)}{dx}$

$\frac{d(-1)}{dx} = 0 \because -1$ is constant with respect to x $\& \frac{d((x-4)^k)}{dx} = \frac{d((x-4)^k)}{dx} \cdot \frac{d(x-4)}{d(x-4)} = \frac{d((x-4)^k)}{d(x-4)} \cdot \frac{d(x-4)}{dx} = k(x-4)^{k-1}$ (remebering that $\frac{dX^n}{dX} = nX^{n-1}$ (for all n constant with respect to X) and $\frac{d(x-a)}{dx} = \frac{dx}{dx} - \frac{da}{dx} = 1 \because$ a is constant with respect to x.

$\therefore f'(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{k \cdot k!}{(2k)!}(x-4)^{k-1}$

Putting k-1 = t, we get : $k = 1 \implies t = 0 \;\&\; k \rightarrow \infty \implies t \rightarrow \infty$

$\therefore f'(x) = \sum_{t=0}^\infty (-1)^{t+2}\frac{(t+1) \cdot (t+1)!}{(2(t+1))!}(x-4)^{t}$

$(-1)^{t+2} = (-1)^t \cdot (-1)^2 = (-1)^t$

Again splitting f'(x) we get :

$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{t=1}^\infty (-1)^t\frac{(t+1) \cdot (t+1)!}{(2(t+1))!}(x-4)^{t}$

differentiating both sides with respect to x, we get :

$f"(x) = \frac{d(-1)}{dx} + \sum_{t=1}^\infty (-1)^t\frac{(t+1) \cdot (t+1)!}{(2(t+1))!}\frac{d((x-4)^{t})}{dx}$

Similiarly as before we get $\frac{d((x-4)^{t})}{dx} = t(x-4)^{t-1} and \frac{d(-1)}{dx} = 0$

$\therefore f"(x) = \sum_{t=1}^\infty (-1)^t\frac{t \cdot (t+1) \cdot (t+1)!}{(2(t+1))!}(x-4)^{t-1}$

Again splitting the function we get :

$f"(x) = \frac{-1}{6} + \sum_{t=2}^\infty (-1)^t\frac{t \cdot (t+1) \cdot (t+1)!}{(2(t+1))!}(x-4)^{t-1}$

Now we need to know f"(4) and very conveniently when we put x = 4 in the second part of the formula of f"(x) derived above, all terms contain a factor of (x-4) and so at x = 4, the second part of f"(x) becomes $0$.

$\therefore f"(x) = \frac{-1}{6}$